# PySide2 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyside2

Does anyone know where I can find a pip-install for PySide2?

It's 2017 and I can't seem to find a pip install or site-package containing the binaries for PySide2. I prefer not to deal with downloading the source code and compiling it myself, as that usually ends up being a huge headache as it's never a smooth process. Also considering it's highly likely someone else has already done it. If I were to be honest here, if I attempted to compile it myself and errors popped up, I wouldn't really know where to begin solving them, nor do I want to spend time doing that.

I just find it hard to believe I can't find it anywhere online or even in PIP when a lot of applications in the VFX industry are switching to PySide2.

I hope someone can help me out.
Thanks

Comment: same problem here, did you find a way?

Comment: nope! sadly still looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are wheels available by Fredrik Averpil [here](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels) built with `Qt 5.6`.
[Claudius Hansch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672926/3233388) provides a wheel using `Qt 5.9`.

In any case, don't forget to either

- set the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable as described [here](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels/issues/69)

or

- create a `qt.conf` file in the folder of your `python.exe` with the content

  ```
  [Paths]
  Prefix = /dir_to_site-packages/PySide2
  Binaries = /dir_to_site-packages/PySide2
  ```

Answer (score 7):

Same Problem...

So i tried to build it. But there are Problems building the WebKit.

Hence my [windows binaries](http://hansch.info/PySide2/) are actually without a webkit binding.

Comment: Looking at your link.. Did you built pyside2 for qt 5.9 linking qt5.6?

Comment: Oh. Yes the first link is Qt 5.9.0 not 5.6.2.
(now the title is correct...)

Comment: you would not have an x64 available by any chance...?

Comment: This is incredible! Thanks @ClaudiusHansch! Can you give a little more info on how you did this? Or was it basically just: https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2_Windows ?

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain it through [PyPI](https://pypi.org/):

```
pip install PySide2
```

or if it fails (most likely because your `pip` executable is bound to python 2) try:

```
pip3 install PySide2
```

or even better:

```
python -m pip install Pyside2
```

This assumes that `python` is bound to Python 3, that way you're really sure about the Python version used, see [Why you should use `python -m pip`](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/).

Comment: Alas, normal windows 10 users get the error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install" trying it via pip

Comment: do you use python 2 or python 3 ?

Comment: Python3. I got it to work by downloading directly from qt.

Answer (score 4):

PySide2 is now available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/) so a simple

`pip install PySide2`

should work on Windows, OSX, and linux!

Comment: Alas, normal windows 10 users get the error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for install" trying it via pip

Comment: It looks like there is no windows package for 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I use Python 3.7 on windows 10 pro, 64bit.

Installing via pip failed for me.

I ended up downloading the wheel from qt directly

[QT official download page](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/)

and install the downloaded wheel which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with installing PySide2 on Windows. I was unsuccessful in finding a way to resolve the issue, but I was able to install PySide6 with pip.