# Installing PySide2 on Windows 10

Tags: python, pyside2

i am trying to install PySide2 on Python3.10: "pip install PySide2" however it shows me these errors:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide2

What can i do please?

Comment: Have you looked at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274151/pyside2-on-windows ?

Comment: I find the most useful answer there to be https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582774/3216427 i.e., download the PySide2 wheel from the Qt downloads web page. PySide2 has also been causing me trouble on Win10, I'll have to give this procedure a try!

Comment: Use python3.9...